# Something like hanoi tower

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have to make a one player game. We have got 4-4 player X's and O's and a blank space (it goes from 0 to 8). It looks like this:

```
|X|X|X|X| |O|O|O|O|
```

I have to swap the X's and O's:

```
|O|O|O|O| |X|X|X|X|
```

The rules are:

1. Any symbol can be moved to an adjacent blank space.
2. X can jump through an O if the place next to the O is blank, and vice versa. For example:

   ```
   |X|X|X| |X|O|O|O|O| -> |X|X|X|O|X| |O|O|O|
   ```
3. There is no other way to move them.

I am stuck with the second rule for like 2 days.

```
public static final int charX = 88;
public static final int charO = 79;
public static final int charSpace = 32;
    //steps[0] = from;
    //steps[1] = to
    // X = 88 ; O = 79 ; Space = 32;
    //char[] table = {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'};
    //int[] table = {88, 88, 88, 88, 32, 79, 79, 79, 79};    



public static int[] ask() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int from;
    int to;
    System.out.println("From where? (0-8)");
    from = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("To where? (0-8)");
    to = sc.nextInt();
    int[] step = {from, to};
    return step;
}

public static boolean isValidMove(int[] steps, int[] table) {

    int from = steps[0];
    int to = steps[1];

    boolean checker = (Math.abs(from - to) != 1 && table[to] != charSpace);
    if (checker == true) {
        return true;
    } else 
        return false;

}

public static int[] validMove(Scanner sc, int to, int from, int[] table) {

    int[] steps = ask();

    from = steps[0];
    to = steps[1];

    while (isValidMove(steps, table)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid move!");
        steps = ask();
        from = steps[0];
        to = steps[1];
    }

    return steps;
}
```

Comment: [Let's discuss this in chat...](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180836/discussion-between-dusungulu-tibor-and-john-kugelman)

Comment: Hey, could you help me with this if iam not bothering you or could you just send me how to do it?

Comment: Hi @JohnKugelman, I'm one of the room owners of the Java room. We don't typically provide tutoring services, unfortunately. Maybe there is someone at your school that can help you, @Düsüngülü?

Answer (score 0):

something along the lines of:

```
for (int i=Math.min(steps[0],steps[1]); i<Math.max(steps[0],steps[1])-1; i++){
    // if table[i] is opposite of table[step[0]]
        // move not valid
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20991027)

Comment: @MartinBarker Why not? It's terse, yes, but at the same time, there is not much to tell. How is that not an answer?

Comment: Because of your saying "something along the lines of", answers should be tailored to the question and be exact to answer them. unless there is a specific reason for not doing so if that is the case you should explain the reasoning as to why your not.